# Any advice or teaching to give to increase efficiency in this simple program?

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I have created an extremely simple program that prompts the user to enter 3 integers, then determines if the inputted variables create a defined triangle. Is there any tips or advice to concise this for increased efficiency? This is an exercise I put forth for myself. I have only be coding for 6 months and am not there yet as far as efficiency, so any help or advice would be great. Thank you.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] triangleInput = EnterSides();
    
        DisplayArray(triangleInput);
        DetermineValidTriangle(triangleInput);
    }

    public static int[] EnterSides()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        int[] triangleInput = new int[3];
        final int numOfSides = 3;
    
        System.out.println("Please enter " + numOfSides + " integers: ");
        for(int x = 0; x < triangleInput.length; ++x)
        {
            triangleInput[x] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        return triangleInput;
    }

    public static void DisplayArray(int[] userInput)
    {
        int[] triangleInput = userInput;
    
        System.out.print("You have entered: " + Arrays.toString(triangleInput));
            
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Side A of triangle is " + triangleInput[0] + ", Side B of triangle is " + 
    triangleInput[1] + ", and Side C of triangle is " + triangleInput[2]);
    }

    public static void DetermineValidTriangle(int[] userInput)
    {
        int[] triangleInput = userInput;
        boolean isTriangle = false;
    
        if(triangleInput[0] + triangleInput[1] > triangleInput[2])
            if(triangleInput[1] + triangleInput[2] > triangleInput[0])
            {
                 if(triangleInput[0] + triangleInput[2] > triangleInput[1])
                {
                     isTriangle = true;
                }
            }
    
        System.out.println();
        if(isTriangle)
            System.out.println("Successful triangle has been built!");
        else
            System.out.println("Sorry, Unsuccessful triangle. The requirement for a triangle is A + B 
is greater than C. B + C is greater than A, and A + C is greater than B.");
    }
```

}

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'efficiency'.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @tgdavies Apologies for lack of clarification. What I mean by "efficiency", is any areas within the code that can be shortened and still produce the desired functionality. Less lines of code, in a broader sense.

Comment: Brevity would be a better term. Efficiency is usually used to mean less time or memory use.

Comment: @tgdavies Ah, okay. Do you see any areas within this code to lessen time or memory use? I realize its almost effortless to compute as it is very rudiment, but hey any areas to improve doesn't hurt.

Comment: You only need one computation:  A + B + C must be > MAX(A,B,C)

Comment: @RickJames Are you sure? What about 1, 1, 3 with 5 > 3, but not a triangle.

Comment: Oops, I left out 2*:  You only need one computation: A + B + C must be > 2*MAX(A,B,C)

Comment: As @MarsAtomic already commented, posting this on codereview would sure be more helpful. Stackoverflow is meant for single-aspect questions, but you'd surely benefit more from an overall review of your code.

Answer (score -3):

Yea delete everything, then replace it with this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//Do not use "import java.util.*;" this will import the entire library in java.util

public class Test1
{

    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int trianglePoint1X = keyboard.nextInt();
        int trianglePoint1Y = keyboard.nextInt();
        int trianglePoint2X = keyboard.nextInt();
        int trianglePoint2Y = keyboard.nextInt();
        int trianglePoint3X = keyboard.nextInt();
        int trianglePoint3Y = keyboard.nextInt();
        //No Arrays, they are unneccessary
        //No Checks, the triangle does not need to be checked to confirm it's a triangle, the user should have freedom to set points
        //Triangle should have it's corners stored in memory instead of it's sides
    }

    public void drawTriangle()
    {
        //connect triangle point 1 with 2
        //connect triangle point 2 with 3
        //connect triangle point 3 with 1   
    }
}
```

Comment: First, you've missed the point of what the OP's code does. Secondly a * import is fine -- it is making names available to the compiler, nothing more.

Comment: I haven't missed the point, it creates a triangle in a really bad way and does unnecessary checks. So you're telling me import does not import?

Comment: Please read how the program is intended to function. The reason why the sides are checked and stored is due to the the Triangle Inequality Theorem, that states the sum of any 2 sides of a triangle must be greater than the measure of the third side. Also, why create 3 separate variables when you can just create an array? The point of an array is to store data types that are the same in one collection.

Comment: You do not run into this problem if you store the 3 corner locations of the triangle instead of the 3 sides. (which should be trianglePoint1X, trianglePoint1Y, trianglePoint2X, trianglePoint2Y, trianglePoint3X, trianglePoint3Y), which I did not correctly write in the code, I'll fix that now.

Comment: This answer misses the point that the task is to specify a triangle by its side lengths, and not the corner coordinates.